# Cookie sent in rediret response are getting ifnored

Tags: http, cookies, http-headers, httpcookie, httpcookiecollection

In login implementation, backend API is redirecting user home page along with setting the session cookie. But when Browser invokes redirect request to home page, this cookie is not getting set-

```
Request URL: https://dfp.prod.us.abc.net/dfp/v1/login?code=D2AE706EBF9D4A15A23C0B0466D2243B&state=OneTwo
Status code: 302
Response headers:
Location: http://dfp-ui.prod.us.abc.net/
Set-Cookie: session-iam-token=MDUxODMyMDE41AQ71z4bAPXX0bvRUUOqdVIah==; Max-Age=1800; Expires=Tue, 10-Sep-2019 07:25:44 GMT; Domain=dfp-ui.prod.us.abc.net; Path=/
```

Now when browser redirects to http://dfp-ui.prod.us.abc.net/, this '

> session-iam-token

is not getting send.

Comment: Of course, because you can't set cookies for another domain. You have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve? Are you trying to accomplish Single Sign On?

Comment: There is existing Cross cutting platform implementation, which requires request to be redirected to backend service- https://dfp.prod.us.abc.net/dfp/v1/login?code=D2AE706EBF9D4A15A23C0B0466D2243B&state=OneTwo
Backend service then validate token(Query param code) and redirects to main page along with cookies generated from token.
I do not get why domains are different, setting a cookie from dfp.prod.us.abc.net, and trying to access it from http://dfp-ui.prod.us.abc.net.

Comment: Yeah sure, but that can't work if the hosts differ. "dfp.prod.us.abc.net" != "dfp-ui.prod.us.abc.net". If you're trying to reinvent Single Sign On, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: So you are saying that cookies works only for same hosts?

Comment: You can [set it for `prod.us.abc.net`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain), but not for a different subdomain.